# Lubuntu upgrade giving bugs

Tags: package-management, 20.04, lubuntu, dependencies

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 using GUI, not terminal, using a phone-based internet connection. After installing this I am unable to login to my home screen by some means like rebooting it redirects me to home where I have to manually setup DSN then running the command `sudo apt upgrade` gives me an error mainly as:- `1gdm3 not processed 2.ubuntu -desktop 3.ubuntu-desktop-minimal`.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any "official" guidance to upgrading from Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (LXDE) to Lubuntu 18.10 (LXQt)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085526/is-there-any-official-guidance-to-upgrading-from-lubuntu-18-04-lts-lxde-to-l)

Comment: The releases notes for all releases from 18.10 have a section which states "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"  (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/)   which is **not** your issue, but even if your issue is resolved.. you'll have other issues too, meaning if you aren't capable of dealing with them, a re-install is recommended.

Comment: No that's not solution to my problem ,I have ubuntu 20.04. in my system

Comment: Problems occur if you upgrade 18.04 to any of 18.10/19.04/19.10/20.04/20.10/21.04 with LXDE/Lubuntu installed.... You said you're coming from 18.04, so my comments apply, even if it's not your actual issue... you've more issues you've not yet discovered was my point...

Comment: Then only solution is to reinstall?

Comment: It would be my recommended solution.  It'll create a cleaner system (a huge part of why upgrades of systems using LXDE in 18.04 are **not recommended**).  You can re-install using "*Manual Partitioning*", re-use your existing partitions, and it'll note your packages, erase system directories, install, then attempt to add back your additional packages (noted earlier) without touching user files (assuming you didn't format). Any global configs in system directories will be lost, but most users don't have those. That'd be my recommendation, backup first anyway, but you'll have done that already

Comment: Can you provide some link ,or video link how to do this? It would be great help, I am not much aware of this, Thank you!

Comment: Manual partitioning is mentioned in the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html) but it's described as an advanced option. I recommended using your existing partitions (thus making it easier as you just use whatever was there before), but I have few details as to your system setup (and don't know your ideapad anyway). I get the feeling english is not your native tongue, if you look at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ you'll note the team provide a number of languages at the discourse (español, français, italiano, 日本語で, 用中文（表達 .. etc) or maybe https://lubuntu.me/links/