# After upgrading to Lubuntu 20.04 launching chrome takes a long time

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, google-chrome

Chrome is taking a long time to open after upgrading to Lubuntu 20.04. I have plenty of memory available:

```
$ free -h 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       894Mi        13Gi       122Mi       1.6Gi        14Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you define “a long time”? Is this 5+ seconds/minutes/hours? What sort of hardware are you using? 

Comment: Upgrading from where?  19.10 reached EOL a long time ago, so a recent upgrade makes little sense at this point in time, and if you were talking about a LXDE release; issues were to be expected which is why upgrades were [*unsupported and discouraged*](https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/)

Comment: @matigo it takes 15 to 20 secs 

h/w : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G630 @ 2.70GHz

Comment: @guiverc upgraded from lubuntu 18.xxx

Comment: If you read the release notes (eg. https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/) you'll have read "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"  Side effects are the issue; some major, some minor; a re-install is the easy fix. How difficult the problems depends on what package(s) you have installed. You've discovered one issue so far....

Comment: Also note - the issue would **not** have occurred if your release was 18.10; as it was the first of the non-LTS releases on the route to Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the end of the last development cycle (with 18.10, 19.04, 19.10 then finally the LTS or 20.04).  We're nearing the end of the next LTS cycle with 20.10-21.10 already released & only final LTS to go.  There is no 18.xx; 18.04 & 18.10 being on different cycles (*18.10 on route to next LTS; 18.04 the end of the prior LTS cycle*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any "official" guidance to upgrading from Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (LXDE) to Lubuntu 18.10 (LXQt)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085526/is-there-any-official-guidance-to-upgrading-from-lubuntu-18-04-lts-lxde-to-l)   *Also note the Lubuntu documentation no longer makes reference to LXDE->LXQt changes; 18.04 reached EOL for flavors back in April 2021; though many LXDE->LXQt upgrade docs were never fully published*

Comment: @guiverc yes upgrade could have screwed my system....thank you for your time.

Comment: I *migrated* **many** 18.04/LXDE boxes to 18.10/LXQt and/or 20.04/LXQt; some as I wanted to upgrade my own boxes but others just for QA (*Quality Assurance*) purposes to explore how it worked & detecting issues/fixes. The results really depended on the packages installed & what configurations had been changed by the users. The box I'm using right now was thus upgraded; but it was ~3 weeks of *not-fun* fiddling & *fighting* to get it so I was happy; other boxes I was happy almost immediately (*they had fewer changes on average*), some had issues later..   removing & re-install packages may help

Comment: The Lubuntu team came to the conclusion it was *potential heartbreak* and whilst we worked to make it as *seamless* as possible (*18.04 to 20.04 was actually better than 18.04 to 18.10*), it was **unsupported** as it was problematic with many issues remaining (*usually unseen/undetected by the user, but quite possibly to be discovered down the road/in-time*).  The Ubuntu infrastructure on which Lubuntu is built; still offers the upgrade (*that cannot be prevented*) but we did all we could to advise users not to upgrade (*as did a good deal of Ubuntu release/upgrade instructions too*)

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last Lubuntu release to use LXDE.

Release notes from 18.10 up provided the warning, eg. on [Lubuntu 20.04.2](https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/) release notes say clearly

> Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop
> environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04
> or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken
> system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please
> do a fresh install

For the 18.04 to 18.10 upgrade; some notes existed for users that didn't want to *clean install*, however they weren't fully published and no longer exist (*may exist in git somewhere rather than a readily readable format*).

If you clean installed Lubuntu 18.10 (the first LXQt release), upgrades were possible from then on again normally.

The problems were not the same for all users, as complexity of problems varied on what packages were installed, and many issues were cosmetic in nature (ie. *you're talking about slowness, rather than not running*), but some items (*I'm thinking menu items that went nowhere*) were more of an issue/distraction.

The warnings on upgrades were there for a reason.

I'd recommend reading the release notes in future. The upgrade you performed was *unsupported* for a reason; problems were to be expected.

Comment: This *may* or *may not* be the issue that is causing `chrome` to be slow; however this is the cause for a number of issues you may not have yet discovered.  Yes you can upgrade (*I'm using such a system right now, but it took me ~3 weeks to get this system so I was fully happy with it*) but issues (*minor or not to minor*) may still be discovered for some time into the future; even subsequent *release-upgrades*.